# Merge several images into one

Tags: c#, wpf, merge, writablebitmap

I have several images, every image placed in writablebitmap. Each images represent one layer, every image contain transparency. I need combine this images into one, combine algorithm: show first image(without changes), after that draw second image, on first, with additional transparency X%, after it third image with additional transparency Y%, etc.
For work i use framework 4.5, programming language C# and VS2012.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the desired result? Do you want to shows this on screen only, or also save it to an image file? Did you yet try anything?

Comment: result need display only, i found only one hardcore way, calculate color result from program, but i think wpf can do it better and faster

Comment: Couldn't you just overlay three Image controls with appropriate `Opacity` values?

Comment: yes i could do it, it is normal way if i have three images, but in case if i work with many images i can have problem with managing this additional images vector

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically create `Image` controls in code and add them to the `Children` collection of a Grid or some other Panel.

Alternatively you may use a Grid as `ItemsPanel` of an ItemsControl, and bind the `ItemsSource` property to a collection of objects that have an `Image` and an `Opacity` propetrty:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In either case the Grid will take care for putting all images on top of each other.

Comment: if i need in real time merge several images it would be normal wave for 10 images with 720p resolution?